# How to view the equivalent of Event Viewer - System Logs on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, event-log

I want to view system level events on a Windows Azure App Service instance. It is a P3v2 instance to be specific.

I can get application logs, web logs and just about every other type of log except for the system logs itself.

We are trying to debug an IO error that is occurring. Here is some more information for reference
https://serverfault.com/questions/1055435/an-unexpected-network-error-occured-winioerror-azure-app-service

If we could get system event logs we might be able to see what else is occurring when our IO error occurs. Eg any azure updates, disk events etc.

How can we view the equivalent of System Logs as found in Windows Event Viewer for a windows azure app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, Azure app service is a PaaS, which would not let you manage the system aspect. You could [enable diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows) on your app service yo get the most information you could get. If you need more about the system site, check the **Azure status** through this [link](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/).

Comment: This is probably as close as I will get. I accepted it as the answer as no one else has a better alternative beyond contacting MS dev support.